# In Elixir, how to sum up all bytes in a non UTF-8 binary?

Tags: elixir

For example, I have a binary `<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>`, how can I sum up all the bytes in it so that I get `15`? This is only an example. The real binaries I'm working on are **not** UTF-8 encoded so that `String.to_charlist/1` always throws exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
<<i <- <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>> >>
|> for(do: i)
|> Enum.reduce(0, &Kernel.+/2)
#⇒ 15
```

Comment: Also `Enum.reduce(0, &Kernel.+/2)` == `Enum.sum`.

Comment: I don't even know such syntax. I think I should pay more attention to `Kernel.SpecialForms`.

Comment: Usually, it’s written as `for <<i <- <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>> >> do: i` but I follow coding style guidelines to start the pipe with the term not with a function call.